# ASP.NET MVC font-awesome works on localhost but not on the web (IIS)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, font-awesome

I saw many solutions on stackoverflow but they doesn't works for me, that's the reason why I wrote this again.

At first I thought IIS is not serving the files, there for i removing the MIME type declaration before re-declaring it.

```
<system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
          <remove fileExtension=".eot" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".eot" mimeType="application/vnd.ms-fontobject" />
          <remove fileExtension=".ttf" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".ttf" mimeType="application/octet-stream" />
          <remove fileExtension=".svg" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".svg" mimeType="image/svg+xml" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff" mimeType="application/font-woff" />
          <remove fileExtension=".woff2" />
          <mimeMap fileExtension=".woff2" mimeType="application/font-woff2" />
    </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Then I add in the `BundleConfig`:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                "~/Content/bootstrap.min.css",
                "~/Content/body.css",
                "~/Content/site.css",
                "~/Content/form.css",
                "~/Content/bootstrap-datepicker.min.css"
            ).Include("~/Content/font-awesome.css", new CssRewriteUrlTransform()));
```

and add in the file `_Layout.cshtml` :

```
@Styles.Render("~/Content/fontawesome")
```

From the NuGet-Paket-Manager I installed:

- FontAwesome.MVC v1.00
- FonAwesome v.4.0.3

Then I tried these examples in the `index.cshtml`

```
<i class="fa fa-ban"></i> ban
<i class="fa fa-2x fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> trash
<i class="fa fa-2x fa fa-file-text-o" aria-hidden="true"></i> pdf
```

It has to run at Edge Chromium

You can see Visual Studio 2017 (included IIS):

[image: Visual Studio]

And here the IIS V 10.0.14393.0  .

[image]

Does someone have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: What did you see from the browser's developer tools and IIS FRT https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, the fonts are displayed correctly locally, but when loaded on the server, only blank squares are displayed. The possible reason  is the filename mentioned in the `src` attribute of the `FontAwesome` CSS file is not the same as the actual font filename.

For more details you can refer to [this link](https://www.itranslater.com/qa/details/2582448294995690496).

Comment: Your going right. Thanks a lot for your help.